# LiveData, setValue in Activity and observe in fragment. Is it possible?

Tags: java, android

How to use livedata, do setValue in activity, and read observe in a fragment, is it possible at all? I know that with this code it calls a new instance twice, but how to do it correctly?

viewmodel:

```
public class PongViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> pongSections;

    public MutableLiveData<String> getPongSections() {
        if (pongSections == null) {
            pongSections = new MutableLiveData<String>();
        }
        return pongSections;
    }

}
```

MainAcitivity:

```
// OnCreate
pongViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PongViewModel.class);


pongViewModel.getPongSections().setValue("test");
```

Fragment:

```
pongViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PongViewModel.class);

       
pongViewModel.getPongSections().observe(this, pongSections -> {
   System.out.println("DATA !!!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a viewmodel scoped to the activity to get the viewmodel from the activity, since at the moment you are right, you created a new viewmodel instance:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    private val pongViewModel: PongViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        //This should fire after updating in the activity now
        pongViewModel.getPongSections().observe(this, pongSections -> {
             System.out.println("DATA !!!");
        });
    }

}
```

[Documentation source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)